# XMLAPI Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected

Tags: php

My site error Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected
https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php
I using xmlapi. It error when call curl_query

```
App::import('Vendor', 'xmlapi');
$domain_name_add = $parts[0] . "." . $parts[1] . "." . $parts[2];
$sub_domain = "*";
$username = Configure::read('asdasdasx-HUY');
$password = Configure::read('hrgfsefasd-HUY');
$targetFolder = '/public_html/';
$xmlapi = new xmlapi(Configure::read('domainsite'));
$xmlapi->set_port(2083);
$xmlapi->password_auth($username, $password);
$xmlapi->set_debug(0); // or you can use 1
$xmlapi->set_output('xml'); // you can use 'json'
$args = array($sub_domain, $domain_name_add, 0, 0, $targetFolder);
$ress = $xmlapi->api2_query($username, 'AddonDomain', 'addaddondomain', array('dir' => $targetFolder, 'newdomain' => $domain_name_add, 'subdomain' => $domain_name_add));
$res = $xmlapi->api1_query($username, 'SubDomain', 'addsubdomain', $args);
```

Header

```
array(
    (int) 0 => 'Authorization: Basic Ym9va3N0cmF2ZWw6SHV5czJEdW5n
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Content-Length: 186

    dir=%2Fpublic_html%2F&newdomain=zingfb.cf&subdomain=zingfb.cf&cpanel_xmlapi_user=bookstravel&cpanel_xmlapi_module=AddonDomain&cpanel_xmlapi_func=addaddondomain&cpanel_xmlapi_apiversion=2'
)
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help if you do not post any details whatsoever? Your code and the API documentation?

Comment: I have put code in topic

Comment: Looks like you put a lot of stuff into a single element in the header array. Shouldn't that be three separate entries in the header and one content instead?

Comment: how code ? please